# SqlTransaction skipping query instead of rollback

Tags: c#, sqltransaction

To manage our database changes I'm writing a simple C# program which will loop over an XML file and apply different statements.

**XML example:**

```
<root>
<update>
    <statement>{{query}}</statement>
    <statement>{{query}}</statement>
</update>
<update>
    <statement>{{query}}</statement>
</update>
</root>
```

I am trying to give the user the option to:

1. Skip statement
2. Skip update
3. Rollback completely
4. Commit and stop

The problem I'm facing is that whenever 1 query fails, the whole transaction is being rollbacked. I want to handle this myself. Is this possible?

**My code**

```
transaction.Save(String.Format("{0}", executedUpdates));
Actions? action = null;

foreach (XmlNode statement in update.ChildNodes)
{
    if (action != null && action.HasValue && action.Value == Actions.Skip_Update) break;

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(statement.InnerText, connection, transaction))
    {
        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Transaction already rollbacked

            // Get input what to do with error
            action = await Executor.HandleError();
            // Handle 
            switch (action)
            {
                case Actions.Skip_Statement:
                    // Carry on with next statement
                    break;
                case Actions.Skip_Update:
                    // Rollback to before this batch
                    transaction.Rollback(String.Format("{0}", executedUpdates));
                    break;
                case Actions.Commit_And_Stop:
                    // Commit and stop
                    transaction.Commit();
                    return true;
                case Actions.Rollback:
                    // Rollback and stop
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @mjwills I tried to explain every action in the catch.

Comment: Why wouldn't you pre-analyze the XML document instead of looping over in order to extract only those statements which shouldn't be skipped and then execute them in a transaction ?

Comment: @DmytroMukalov The XML file is in theory a correct document which should be executed from top to bottom. This is just a precaution for when there is an error in the XML when going to production.

Comment: OK, merely extending this logic to the execution phase: during the first pass if some statements fail you can rollback the initial transaction and make a second execution pass with only succeeded statements wrapped into transaction (in case if skip actions were chosen).

Comment: @DmytroMukalov thanks! I'm now restarting the transaction completely after finding an error. The action chosen gets saved (skip statement `x` or update `y`). This happens until there are no more errors, that's when I commit the complete transaction. Thanks for thinking with me